# NodeJS & React w/ DevExpress - import variable throwing syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, devexpress

I have a combo of ReactJS and DevExpress for my client side, and I'm running my API using Express currently on my localhost since I haven't deployed/launched yet.

My issue is that I'm trying to import a variable that I exported from one of my modules to use in a SQL query, and I'm running into Syntax errors in my console.  It's caught on my DevExpress TreeList (encapsulated in < >'s) and thinking < is an invalid syntax.  I've confirmed my filepaths are good, my SQL queries are targeting what I need and where I need it, it's just this one odd Syntax error I can't get around. The end goal is when my onFocusedRowChanged function fires, to have my Grid load inside my Tree (nested, more or less) I left my SQLdb login info as empty strings on purpose for this post :)

Any ideas what could be causing the console to think a standard < > is improper would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my server.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

import pkg from 'file:///src/Tree/WireTree.js'
const { cellValue } = pkg;

app.use(cors());
app.get('/wiretree', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require("mssql");
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        server: '', 
        database: '',
        options: {
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            instanceName: '',
        }
    };
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var treeRequest = new sql.Request();
            treeRequest.query(
                "SELECT wc.categoryID, Name, Filter, ParentCategoryID as ParentID from wirecategory wc INNER JOIN wirecategorytree wct on wc.CategoryID = wct.CategoryID ORDER BY [wct].[order]", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});

app.get('/wiremessage', function (req, res) {
    var sql = require("mssql");
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        server: '', 
        database: '',
        options: {
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            instanceName: '',
        }
    };
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var wireRequest = new sql.Request();
            wireRequest.query(
                "SELECT wm.WireID, wm.ReceiveTime, wcv.DisplayValue as Category, wpv.DisplayValue as Priority, wm.Headline from wiremessage as wm JOIN wireservice as ws on wm.WireServiceID = ws.WireServiceID JOIN wirecategoryvalue as wcv on wm.Category = wcv.value and wcv.WireCategoryGroupID = ws.WireCategoryGroupID JOIN wirepriorityvalue as wpv on wm.Priority = wpv.Value and wpv.WirePriorityGroupID = ws.WirePriorityGroupID WHERE" + `${cellValue}`, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(4741, function () {
    console.log('Server is running on port 4741...');
});
```

Here's the React/DevExpress module it's trying to import and choking on:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TreeList, SearchPanel, Scrolling, Lookup } from 'devextreme-react/tree-list';
import 'devextreme-react/text-area';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import WireGrid from '../Tables/Wires/WireGrid.js'

const expandedRowKeys = [1];
// const allowedPageSizes = [5, 10, 15, 20];
class WireTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jsonData: null,
  }
  this.onFocusedRowChanged = this.onFocusedRowChanged.bind(this);
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:4741/wiretree";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log('returned tree data: ', data);
        this.setState({
            'jsonData' : data.recordset,
        })
        console.log('returned Tree state: ', this.state.jsonData);
}

onFocusedRowChanged(e) {
  var rowData = e.row && e.row.data,
  cellValue;
  if(rowData) {
    cellValue = e.component.cellValue(e.row.rowIndex, 'Filter');
    module.export = cellValue.toString();
    if (!cellValue) {
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log('cellValue: ', cellValue);
      
    }
  }
} 

  render() {
    return (
      <TreeList
        id="wireTree"
        dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
        dataStructure="plain"
        rootValue=""
        defaultExpandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
        columnAutoWidth={true}
        keyExpr="categoryID"
        parentIdExpr="ParentID"
        wordWrapEnabled={true}
        focusedRowEnabled={true}
        virtualModeEnabled={true}
        onFocusedRowChanged={this.onFocusedRowChanged}
      >
        <SearchPanel visible={true} />
        <Scrolling mode="standard" />
        <Lookup
          dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
          valueExpr="ID"
          displayExpr="Search" />
      </TreeList>
    );
  }
}

export default WireTree;
```

Here's the error my console is showing:

```
<TreeList
   ^
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
        at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)
```

Last but not least, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "express",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dataType" : "json",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bearer": "^0.0.20",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "~4.3.2",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.8.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.10.0",
    "mssql": "^7.1.3",
    "o.js": "^1.3.1",
    "odata": "^1.3.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "ssl-root-cas": "^1.3.1",
    "tedious": "^11.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is all screwed up, I strongly suggest you to fix it, especially when posting code for other to look at

Comment: This error usually occurs when jsx is not transpiled (ex with babel). I don't see babel or anything like it listed

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer True, sorry for the confusion, that's the package.json for my API but I do have babel core and babel node in my React app client side.

Comment: And you have a babal config with the necessary transforms or preset? (Babel won't just transform jsx on its own without you explicitly telling it to) `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` and `@babel/preset-react` (respectively)

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer uhoh, I definitely do not ... should those go in client side, API side or both?

Comment: Client-side for sure; server-side if you use client-side code (ex server-side rendering, aka SSR)

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer so I just added it to my client-side and API, and I still got returned: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)``` Any ideas?

Comment: The configuration is probably not getting consumed. Babel has 3 different kinds of configuration files, which work in specific circumstances. Very likely, you (like many people) are using the wrong one. Try adding a syntax error to your babel config (if it's not in package.json); if it does not blow up, the file is not being picked up. Also note that some babel config files MUST start with a period/dot `.`

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer Gotcha, thanks so much for the help! Should all my babel's be under  my dependencies in my package.json or my devDependencies, btw?

Comment: Neither: your babel config would be a sibling of dependencies and devDependencies

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a closing `}` in your `onFocusedRowChanged` function